# What are the problems/difficulties I might run into when using ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, activex

I need some expert information about ActiveX and some valuable experience reports from those that already used it.

The situation is the following: ~90% of all of our applications are created as web apps with ASP.net WebForms. We're now in the process of switching to a more modern approach, creating rich client JavaScript apps. **However**, In one of the recent projects, a strong requirement from the customer is the ability to directly print to a (previously configured) printer attached to the user's workstation. Yes, **no printer dialogs, print previews etc..** It has to be fast.

Obviously this is a scenario where you would rather use a **desktop app** than a web based one. Still, we would like to benefit from our existing web dev knowledge and are therefore considering to write that very specific, isolated printing functionality as an ActiveX control (*IE dependency is not an issue*).

Now, since the word "ActiveX" alone causes disgust for some people, I'd like to hear what might be **the potential problems at using such a (old) technology** or do u directly consider me to make it as a desktop app and completely forget about it?? Or are there alternatives??

Comment: You could use a Java applet in place of ActiveX

Comment: We thought about that as well..where do you see the advantage? Browser independence??

Comment: That and you are using something other than ActiveX that has more compatibility and standards compliance. Also, there are more people making Java applets than ActiveX controls.

Comment: Yes with a Java applet included on the page. This should help you http://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet

Comment: @Devin thx for the link...there might be something useful, however the level of printing is a bit too low-level. We have complex reports that we generate with Aspose on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary challenge you'll face is the learning curve; beyond that the biggest problems are the potential for you messing up and opening a security hole (for example, what happens if a malicious third party loads your activex control on their phishing site? can they use it to print things?), etc.

For the learning curve, I highly recommend looking at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org), which can be used to create browser plugins that work on IE (as an ActiveX control) as well as Firefox, chrome, safari, etc (as a NPAPI plugin). Though ActiveX is an "old" technology, it's still used *extensively* in the modern day; for example, Flash, Silverlight, Quicktime, and other "plugins" like that are all activex controls in IE.

Comment: +1 for Firebreath, although I'd seriously probe the customer's requirement before committing to writing native code at all if you can help it. Doing it using a plugin will add months to the project, just to avoid a printer dialog...

Comment: Thx for pointing to Firebreath. The customer requirements are not negotiable..unfortunately. Today I quickly coded a prototype to read out the installed printers and to directly print to one of them and it works perfectly, everything with ActiveX and JavaScript in the browser. The open points are still how such ActiveX components are properly updated, i.e. when it is necessary to release a new version, bugfixes...are there any know best practices?

Comment: all of that information is available on the FireBreath.org website; for more specific questions try the Live Chat link (IRC)